# How to add more than 4 .jtl files to merge and create summary report in Jmeter GUI

Tags: jmeter

I am using Apache Jmeter version 3.0 for my performance load test of a system.
I have 5 test servers where Jmeter test scripts are run (5 different .jmx files run simultaneously) and generate 5 different .jtl files.

After my test, I could only merge (on JMeter GUI -> jp@gc - Merge Results) maximum 4 .jtl files, which I think the default number of files I could merge. While adding the 5th .jtl file, the 'Add Row' button gets disabled on the Jmeter GUI (as seen in the picture below).

How can I modify/configure to include more than 4 .jtl files to merge and create Summary Report in Jmeter GUI ? (note that, for aggregated report creation I would like to use Jemeter GUI).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [MergeResultsGui](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/tools/mergeresults/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/vizualizers/MergeResultsGui.java#L111) source code

```
private static final int MAX_FILE_HANDLES = 4;
```

So there is no way to merge more than 4 files **at a time**.

The easiest way is doing it step-by-step, like:

1. Merge 4 .jtl files into 1 "uber" .jtl
2. Merge 5th .jtl file with the "uber" .jtl

Also be aware that you can run these files using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool and get real-time stats while the test runs and single .jtl file as the output. Check out [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests) guide for more details.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. I'll follow your solution.